# Unattended SDL Tridion 9.1 sites installation throws 500 error for topology manager

Tags: installation, sites-9.1

We are implementing an unatteded install of an SDL 9.1 environment.
During the installation, there is an error, and after some research, we find that the topology manager throws the following error

```
Exception information: 
Exception type: ConfigurationErrorsException 
Exception message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config line 111)
at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)
at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies()
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart()
at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)



Request information: 
Request URL: http://localhost:81/ttm201601/CmEnvironments 
Request path: /ttm201601/CmEnvironments 
User host address: 127.0.0.1 
User:  
Is authenticated: False 
Authentication Type:  
Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE.
```

We already had a look at this possible fix (which looks similar) https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000005294 but this didn't seem to help.

Is there something we're missing ?

We install this in a Windows Server 2019 environment

Answer (score 2):

After some more research, it turns out that a previous failed install was causing this problem.
The previous install had placed some files, but most likely not everything.

We were able to fix it by first uninstalling the failed installation, and then running the unattended install again.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK - SDL Tridion Sites 9.1 - you need to manually install the .Net framework 4.8 and .NET Core Runtime 2.2 manually prior to install.

**Note:** These pre-requisites not comes with SDL Tridion Sites installation media.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check which version of Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions is installed in your Server environment.

Sometimes the AssemblyVersion will be different from the AssemblyFileVersion; and the AssemblyVersion should be referenced and check web.config is referenced to which version of the assembly. Need to insatll that version or other way update web.config for the version which you have installed.